# How can i use symbol.barcode classes and methods?

Tags: c++, mfc, barcode, symbols, motorola

I have a Motorola MC9000 device with barcode scanner. And i want to run it (scanner) inside my C++ MFC programm. I downloaded Motorola EMDK. There are many samples using Symbol.Barcode methods, i.e

```
Symbol.Generic.Reader.Actions.NewReaderData()
Symbol.Generic.Reader.Actions.Actions.Enable()
Symbol.Generic.Reader.Actions.Actions.Disable()
```

but i dont know how to let my VS2008 know about these classes. Inside archive i found symbol.dll and symbol.barcode.dll, but I'm not very familiar with link options, please  tell me what must i do with these assemblies ?